# how to render pages on dashboard in react using material Ui

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, frontend, mern

I am facing little bit difficulty, I have to manage my dashboard using material-UI with other components
the process of application is that first I want to open login foam and then the dashboard and I am willing to change just the right-center part of the dashboard with the different component by selecting the listItem option

here is my Dashboard

[image]

here is all routes defined on my App.js

```
  <Provider store={store}>
    <BrowserRouter>
        < Routes>
          <Route exact path='/' element={<Login/>} />
          <Route exact path='/dashboard' element={<Dashboard/>} />
          <Route exact path='/product' element={<Product/>}/>
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>
```

currently, the issue is that when I am going to login which is on my `"/"` route and after the authentication the app navigate on the dashboard but when I click my product tab so the dashboard is disappear there

here is my product page

[image]

i am willing to that all pages should to render just in text area where text is showing

Answer (score 0):

I will make some assumptions before answering your question:

- You want the Dashboard view to be always available
- The Dashboard view's white screen should receive different content depending on the route that you're currently in

In your app you should have some sort of `Layout` which wraps the entire App. You are using `react-router` `v6` so most probably the way to go it will be this:

```
  <Provider store={store}>
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Layout />}>
            <Route exact path='/login' element={<Login/>} />
            <Route exact path='/dashboard' element={<Dashboard/>} />
            <Route exact path='/product' element={<Product/>}/>
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>
```

And in your `Layout` component, something like this:

```
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

const Layout = () => (
  <main>
    <Outlet />
  </main>
);
```

[You can check the `react-router` documentation for `<Outlet />`](https://reactrouterdotcom.fly.dev/docs/en/v6/api#outlet)

Did it help?

EDIT: Forgot to say that yout `<Layout />` view should have the Drawer that you're showing in your first screenshot, and the white space is where `Outlet` should be.

Comment: Yes you understand my question thanks for that and I understand your first explanation about routers but I don't understand the layout code, basically, my all components have their own folders and as I understand your layout code so I created one more layout component file  and I paste that code there ... the first thing is that it has no export code so i have to get errors